# Where can I download old stable builds of Chromium from?

Tags: chromium

I've found a Website containing a lot of builds of Chromium but the folders are named after the build number (those numbers are not visibly connected to Chromium version numbers) and there is no information if the builds are developer, beta or stable builds.

[Here](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html) is the link:

I would like to be able to chose from those folders only the stable builds of Chromium.

For example if I want a stable build of Chromium 35.0, how can I find it?

Thanks

Later edit: I need 64-bit binary releases for Windows 7

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: Chromium doesn't offer old releases on its website for security reasons. But you can install any release for Windows (32/64) from the chocolatey repository (link show more for all versions) https://chocolatey.org/packages/chromium/

Comment: Note to self: Version-history link:  https://chocolatey.org/packages/chromium/#versionhistory

Answer (score 34):

Another way, as described [here](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium):

1. Look up the version number (for example "44.0.2403.157") in the [Position Lookup](https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/)
2. In this case it returns a base position of "330231". This is the commit of where the 44 release was branched, back in May 2015.
3. Open the [continuous builds archive](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html)
4. Click through on your platform (Linux/Mac/Win)
5. Paste "330231" into the filter field at the top and wait for all the results to XHR in.
6. Eventually I get a perfect hit: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/330231/

   - Sometimes you may have to decrement the commit number until you find one.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: You need to have an exact version number to look to look up the base position.  Just using "70" won't work.  You can find a list of all the stable version numbers here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+refs

Comment: https://vikyd.github.io/download-chromium-history-version/

Comment: 'Position Lookup' no longer works (as of 2024). Any alternative?

Answer (score 10):

### Source

You can find the stable channel releases [here.](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+refs) For instance, the last v35 release is [this one](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/35.0.1916.8).

---

### Binary

If you want a binary, it should be easy to find one based on the v35 stable build.

- If you run GNU/Linux, you should be able to find old packages (eg. the Ubuntu 64-bit package is [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecmiller/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-browser-stable-daily/+build/6029868)).
- For Windows, you might download a [Portable Apps version](http://crportable.sourceforge.net/) ([file list](https://sourceforge.net/projects/crportable/files/))
- I'm not sure where the best place is for OS X, but as an example, here's a [build](http://www.freesmug.org/news:125) based on v35 stable from the FreeSMUG user group.

Comment: Thanks, those links are very useful. However, I downloaded and installed three versions of Chromium from Portable Apps and one of them crashes after install when I try to launch it, and the other two work but they are are developer builds.

Comment: Tried two more, they are both developer versions.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if there's even such a thing officially as a "stable" binary. GNU/Linux distros, etc, use that term for Chromium releases, but I don't think the Chromium devs themselves do. If you want a Windows binary, your best bet may be to find a version that's packaged for a major distro and regard that as a stable build. See if you can download matching binary from Portable Apps (or elsewhere). Otherwise you could try to build it yourself.

Comment: Shortcut for macOS : https://sourceforge.net/projects/osxportableapps/files/Chromium/

Comment: @pyrocrasty Where I can find 64 bits old Windows builds ?

Answer (score 4):

All Chromium Portable releases for Windows (binary format):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/crportable/files/

Answer (score 0):

I would try to look at https://github.com/henrypp/chromium/releases, and search "**(stable)**" text in notes. Using the "next" button somewhere on the bottom of website you can go back to previous versions. There is no archaic versions but few previous stable versions can be found.